# (log n)^k = O(n)? For k greater or equal to 1

Tags: big-o, notation, logarithm, proof

`(log n)^k = O(n)? For k greater or equal to 1.`

My professor presented us with this statement in class, however I am not sure what it means for a function to a have a time complexity of O(n). Even stuff like `n^2 = O(n^2)`, how can a function f(x) have a run time complexity?

As for the statement how does it equal O(n) rather than O((logn)^k)?

Comment: From the FAQ: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much**."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> (log n)^k = O(n)?

Yes. The definition of big-Oh is that a function `f` is in O(g(n)) if there exist positive constants N and c, such that for all `n > N`: `f(n) <= c*g(n)`. In this case `f(n)` is `(log n)^k` and `g(n)` is `n`, so if we insert that into the definition we get: "there exist constants N and c, such that for all `n > N`: `(log n)^k <= c*n`". This is true so `(log n)^k` is in O(n).

> how can a function f(x) have a run time complexity

It doesn't. Nothing about big-Oh notation is specific to run-time complexity. Big-Oh is a notation to classify the growth of functions. Often the functions we're talking about measure the run-time of certain algorithms, but we can use big-Oh to talk about arbitrary functions.

Answer (score 7):

`f(x) = O(g(x))` means `f(x)` grows slower or comparably to `g(x)`.

Technically this is interpreted as "We can find an `x` value, `x_0`, and a scale factor, `M`, such that   this size of `f(x)` past `x_0` is less than the scaled size of `g(x)`." Or in math:

`|f(x)| < M |g(x)| for all x > x_0`.

So for your question:

`log(x)^k = O(x)?` is asking : is there an x_0 and M such that
`log(x)^k < M x for all x>x_0`.

The existence of such `M` and `x_0` can be done using various limit results and is relatively simple using L'Hopitals rule .. however it can be done without calculus.

---

The simplest proof I can come up with that doesn't rely on L'Hopitals rule uses the Taylor series

```
e^z = 1 + z + z^2/2 + ... = sum z^m / m!
```

Using `z = (N! x)^(1/N)` we can see that

```
e^(x^(1/N)) = 1 + (N! x)^(1/N) + (N! x)^(2/N)/2 + ... (N! x)^(N/N)/N! + ...
```

For x>0 all terms are positive so, keeping only the Nth term we get that

```
e^((N! x)^(1/N)) = N! x / N! + (...) 
                 = x + (...)
                 > x  for x > 0
```

Taking logarithms of both sides (since log is monotonic increasing), then raising to Nth power (also monotonic increasing since N>0)

```
(N! x)^(1/N) > log x  for x > 0
N! x > (log x)^n      for x > 0
```

Which is exactly the result we need, `(log x)^N < M x` for some `M` and all `x > x_0`, with `M = N!` and `x_0=0`